# Delete all occurrences of an item in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Below code takes an item as argument and delete all occurrences of the item in linked list.It works well with my testing. is there anything that i am missing? can this code be improved further?

```
void
LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key) {
   Node *temp = head;
   Node *prev = head;
   while(temp!=NULL) {
      if(temp->item == key){
         if(temp == head) {
            head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = head;
         } else {
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = prev->next;
         }
      } else {
         prev = temp;
         temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the code at all or not? Perhaps try the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code has a bug. When deleting the `head` node, `prev` is not updated correctly (i.e.) it will still point to the *deleted* head node.

I've annotated your code and applied a fix [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *prev = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->item == key) {
            // NOTE/BUG: after this, prev will _still_ be pointing to the
            // _deleted_ head node
            // NOTE/FIX: to fix this, prev must be set to the _updated_ head
            // node
            if (temp == head) {
                head = temp->next;

                // NOTE/FIX: add this:
#if 1
                prev = head;
#endif

                delete temp;
                temp = head;
            }
            else {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
                temp = prev->next;
            }
        }
        else {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

There *may* be another bug as well. And, I think there's a way to simplify things a bit. So, for comparison:

```
void
LinkedList::DeleteAllOccurences(int key)
{
    Node *temp;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *next;

    for (temp = head;  temp != NULL;  temp = next) {
        next = temp->next;

        if (temp->item != key) {
            prev = temp;
            continue;
        }

        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;
        else
            head = next;

        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `std::list<>` and let it do all of the heavy lifting. Below is an example implementation that should fit what you need:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create a list.
    list<int> myList;

    // Add some numbers: 2, 3, 2, and 5.
    myList.push_back(2);
    myList.push_back(3);
    myList.push_back(2);
    myList.push_back(5);

    // Print the contents of the list.
    // Will output 2, 3, 2, 5.
    for(auto item : myList)
        cout << item << endl;

    // Remove all numbers equal to 2.
    myList.remove(2);

    // Print the contents of the list.
    // Will output 3 and 5.
    for(auto item : myList)
        cout << item << endl;

    return 0;
}
```